Como trabalhar com expressão ternária, em Razor Page?
@readonly = Model.pessoaId != null ? "true" : "false"
Estou tentando atribuir ao 'readonly' o valor conforme a condição. O valor está sendo inserido corretamente, mas o estado do input não está mudando. No caso de 'pessoaId == null', o input deveria cficar no modo de edição, mas permanece no modo leitura.

precisa envolver entre parênteses a sua expressão para ser aceita na view, ou pode colocar o bloco entre "chaves" @{ }
